# Android: Making base ViewGroup for layouts to extend

Tags: android, android-layout

Which would be the correct way to use abstract `ViewGroup` class like this:

- MyCustomFrameLayout - FrameLayout - MyCustomViewGroup
- MyCustomRelativeLayout - RelativeLayout - MyCustomViewGroup

So I have some default drawing, touch handling, scrolling etc implemented in `MyCustomViewGroup` and now I need to get `FrameLayout` and `RelativeLayout` to extend that `ViewGroup` instead of default.

Thanks.

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to achieve, please describe your question in more detail.

Comment: To make it simple I need to have Framelayout to extend CustomViewGroup and still be a FrameLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is multiple inheritance and java does not support that.

There are two ways to achieve this.

1: Create separate subclass of framelayout, relativelaout. Put your common code in one class and use the object of that class to call those functions inside your custom classes.

2: Create a wrapper class that has an object of this ViewGroup type and perform those functions on that object.

Comment: Yep thought so, but just needed to be clear that there isn't any fancy tricks to use, thanks.